# React Native SectionList Rendering Incorreclty

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm attempting to bind an array of objects to a SelectionList, it appears to be binding but its rendering each character as an individual list item rather than a single item.

Here is my code:

[image]

r: GetRecipesResponse is a list of objects that I am then converting to an array, this is visible to the left of the above, the rendering issue is apparent on the right.

```
interface States {
    response: GetRecipesResponse;
    globalItems: any[];
    isModalVisible: boolean;
    selectedItem: any;
    selectedItemUnit: any;
}

export class MatrixScreen extends BaseNetworkScreen<GetRecipesResponse, Props, States> {

    itemWidth: number = 100;
    itemMargin: number = 3;
    selectedItemsArray: any[];

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.selectedItemsArray = [];

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            response: null,
            globalItems: this.selectedItemsArray,
            isModalVisible: false,
            selectedItem: null,
            selectedItemUnit: null
        };
    }
}

renderSelectLists(r: GetRecipesResponse): any {

    var arr = [];
    for (var key in r.data.recipe) {
      arr.push(r.data.recipe[key].name);
    }

    let sections = []
    for (const key in this.state.globalItems) {
        if (this.state.globalItems.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            sections.push({
                data: this.state.globalItems[key],
                key: key,
                unit: this.state.selectedItemUnit
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={styles.addContainer}>

                <Text>Press To Add Item</Text>

                <SectionList

                    sections={[{ data: arr }]}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.SectionListItemS} onPress={this.loadMatrixModal.bind(this, item)}> {item} </Text>}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index: any) => index}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.removeContainer}>
                <Text>Press To Remove Item</Text>
                <SectionList
                    sections={sections}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Text style={styles.SectionListItemS} onPress={this.removeSectionListItem.bind(this, index)}> {item} </Text>}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index: any) => item}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Logging out "sections" to the console after it's been defined returns the following:

[image]

Update:

If I add `renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Text style={styles.SectionListItemS} onPress={this.removeSectionListItem.bind(this, index)}> {console.log(item)} {item} </Text>}`

Interestingly it outputs the following to the console,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to build my object like so:

```
var data = {name: item, qty: unit};
var builtObject = {data: [data]};
```

Then I can push the object to an array and set the state of globalItems to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're not rendering the property you want.

What you need is to access the `data` property of each `item`.

So you need to change:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.SectionListItemS} onPress={this.loadMatrixModal.bind(this, item)}> {item} </Text>}
```

To this:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.SectionListItemS} onPress={this.loadMatrixModal.bind(this, item)}> {item.data} </Text>}
```

Notice how I changed `{ item }` to `{ item.data }`, that's because `item` holds the entire `item` object and you want to render the `data` property.

Comment: This produces the same result except it doesn't render the text, simply blank entries. My understanding is that the as long as the array contains a data property it will render, take the following example that works correctly,  "sections={[{data: ['item1', 'item2']}]}" ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html